# how to migrate from drupal 7 to drupal 8 beta

Tags: drupal, upgrade, drupal-8

I'm trying to find a way to migrate my Drupal 7 website to Drupal 8. I want to migrate all my content types.

How do I do that?

Comment: Drupal 8 comes with a built-in migration system. http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/migrating-content-drupal-8

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2257723 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best answered in the following post:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/105781/migrate-from-drupal-7-to-drupal-8

This is a moving target but the bottom line is leveraging the Migrate module which is shipped in core Drupal 8 is where you want to spend your efforts.

Have fun!

Nick

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Drupal module: [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate).

> Back up and restore your Drupal MySQL database, code, and files or migrate a site between environments. Backup and Migrate supports gzip, bzip and zip compression as well as automatic scheduled backups.

You must be very careful with this Module, because it is in still in dev.